# Preserve file permission while creating zip using zip4j

Tags: java, zip4j

I want to preserve file permissions of files while creating Zip.

I am generating Zip using the following code :

```java
src.setExecutable(true);
src.setReadable(true);
src.setWritable(true);

ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(destZipFile);

ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();
parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE);
parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);
parameters.setIncludeRootFolder(false);

zipFile.addFile(src, parameters);
```

Expecting: while unzipping the file with all permission

Actual: file with 644 permission

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Windows and linux both

Comment: Generating zip from windows. Move it to linux and testing it

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the newer version of the library (> 2.x). This issue should be fixed from v2.x on.